# Joint, two-sided chance constraint of MILP reformulation of a logical constrain

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, logical-constraints, chance-constraints

I reformulated the logical constraint $x =   \min\{y,z\}$ as this MILP problem
$$
\begin{array}{ll}
x &\leq y \\
x &\leq z \\
x &\geq y-M(1-w) \\
x &\geq z-Mw
\end{array}
$$
in which $M$ is a large positive constant and $w$ is a binary variable. Let $y$ be a continuous variable and $z$ be the uncertain parameter.
Now, if I want to write the main constraint as a probabilistic constraint, I will have $\mathbb{P}(\text{set of four constraints})\geq 1-\epsilon$.

The **first question** is whether this chance constraint is joint and not single, and the **second question** is since the main variable $x$ has both lower and upper bounds (but with different values and not with the same value with the opposite sign), is it two-sided and not one-sided?